# How can I make a pc unity game work on phone too?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a 3d block slide game, where you have to bypass obstacles to get to the finish line.(pretty basic)
You press A and it goe's left, you press D and it goes's right.
I want to make the game for android phone too so i right some code to implement these:
when i press anywhere on the left side on the screen to go left like you would press a button and the same with the right part. (i am not too good at righting code)  and it works very strange, not as it should do.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TouchControls : MonoBehaviour {


public float moveSpeed;
private object mousePos;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    
}

 private void FixedUpdate()
{
    TouchMove();
}

void TouchMove()
{

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {

        Vector3 mosuePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (mosuePos.x > 1)
        {

            transform.Translate(moveSpeed, 0, 0);

        }
        else if (mosuePos.x < -1)
        {
            transform.Translate(-moveSpeed, 0, 0);
        }
        }

}
```

}

Comment: Please use the correct tags. `[unityscript]` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in previous Unity versions and is long**deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly in `c#`. Also it is not specifically related to VisualStudio at all

Answer (score 0):

You could add two panels, one on the left and the other on the right, and add button behaviour to those, adding a function like MoveToRight()
{ transform.Translate(moveSpeed, 0, 0); } and get the mouse button down, the unity handles mouse inputs as finger inputs when set to android.

Comment: How do I add thouse 2 panels?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... You can simple use the UI. Right click -> UI -> Panel

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Touch` if you want touch support ;)

```
void TouchMove()
{
    // If touch is not supported use the mouse as fallback
    if(Input.touchSupported)
    {
        if(Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            HandleTouch(touch.position);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            HandleTouch(Input.mousePosition);
        }
    }
}

void HandleTouch (Vector2 touchPosition)
{
    // Checks if the touch/click is on the right or left half of the screen
    if (touchPosition.x > Screen.width / 2f)
    {
        transform.Translate(moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.Translate(-moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
}
```